# map.querySourceFeatures on different zoom levels

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

map.querySourceFeatures is returning different number of objects 
on different zoom levels.
Is there a way to get all the data, not only visible?
Thanks

```
var feature = map.querySourceFeatures("mapbox-postcodes", {
        sourceLayer: ['Distribution'],
        filter: ['==', ['to-string', ['get', 'name']], "someCode"]
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

No. [`querySourceFeatures()`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#querysourcefeatures) always returns features which have been loaded into the current viewport. It can't access anything other than the current zoom level.

> The domain of the query includes all currently-loaded vector tiles and GeoJSON source tiles: this function does not check tiles outside the currently visible viewport.